# Is there a way to generate / emit source-maps for TypeScript interfaces?

Tags: typescript, babeljs

#### Problem definition

My codebase is comprised of TypeScript and JavaScript, which is transpiled down by [Babel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Babel_(transcompiler)), which is also generating the source-maps. I have a bunch of TypeScript *interfaces* and want to know if there is a way to generate the source-maps for those interfaces, so that they can be referred to while debugging.

#### Digging

Doing a bit of digging it seems, while transpiling, the interfaces are brought to where they're being used in JavaScript. Is there a feature flag I'm missing?

#### Example

```js
export interface SomeInterface {
  name: string
  phone_no: string
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my point of view, TypeScript is just a wrapper for JavaScript, with type checking. It means we can assign anything into any variable in JavaScript. But TypeScript restricts that by type checking.

TypeScript holds a **static type system** and so it will be activated at compile time. When we transpile TypeScript code into JavaScript, there won't be any type checking anymore.

So you can't generate a *source-maps* for types (interfaces).

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to convert the interface to JS classes, or objects, which very much exist in JS

Comment: JS is a dynamically typed language. If JS does something like you mentioned, it means transpilation may convert TS interfaces into JS something and JS also may validate things in compilation level (static type checking). So there may not be such a thing happen I guess. Let's see! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Interfaces only exist during type checking. They are not compiled, they don't exist at runtime, and they don't exist in the compiled output.

In short: *there is nothing to map*.